# I tried to remove specific element if its output is empty in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to remove Error Description element if it contains  empty value using xslt. i tried lot of options but it does not work.

For example if inside Acknowledgement all the element get null then output get empty acknowledgement so I want remove acknowledgement element empty tag.

below is xml and xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<updateDocumentStatusResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001">
   <Acknowledgement>
      <Result>SUCCESS</Result>
      <ErrorCode>ErrorCode1375</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorDescription></ErrorDescription>
   </Acknowledgement>
</updateDocumentStatusResponse>
```

XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.be/CSM/v001" xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions" xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator" xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas" xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue" xmlns:oraxsl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001" exclude-result-prefixes=" xsd oracle-xsl-mapper xsi xsl ns1 ns0 mhdr oraext xp20 xref socket dvm oraxsl"
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"



                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
   <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>

      <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
         <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="WSDL">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../WSDLs/CommgrService_v001.wsdl"/>
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="updateDocumentStatusResponse" namespace="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001"/>
         </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>        
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>


   </oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
   <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ns1:Output>
         <ns1:CommunicationResponse>           
            <ns1:Acknowledgement>
               <ns1:Result>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:Result"/>
               </ns1:Result>
               <ns1:ErrorCode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:ErrorCode"/>
               </ns1:ErrorCode>
               <ns1:ErrorDescription>
                  <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:ErrorDescription"/>
               </ns1:ErrorDescription>
            </ns1:Acknowledgement>
         </ns1:CommunicationResponse>
      </ns1:Output>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: To make it simple, can't you add `<xsl:if test="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:ErrorDescription != ''">` before creating `<ns1:ErrorDescription>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done if you're not thinking something big:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:ErrorDescription) != ''">
         <ns1:ErrorDescription>
              <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:ErrorDescription"/>
         </ns1:ErrorDescription>
</xsl:if>
```

**Edit:**

One way to achieve this using extension function like `exsl:node-set` or `msxsl:node-set` to be able to further process a result tree fragment created in another template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.be/CSM/v001" xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions" xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator" xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas" xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue" xmlns:oraxsl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001" exclude-result-prefixes=" xsd oracle-xsl-mapper xsi xsl ns1 ns0 mhdr oraext xp20 xref socket dvm oraxsl"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
<oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
    <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="WSDL">
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../WSDLs/CommgrService_v001.wsdl" />
            <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="updateDocumentStatusResponse" namespace="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001" />
        </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
    </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
</oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
<!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <ns1:Output>
            <ns1:CommunicationResponse>
                <ns1:Acknowledgement>
                    <ns1:Result>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:Result" />
                    </ns1:Result>
                    <ns1:ErrorCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:ErrorCode" />
                    </ns1:ErrorCode>
                    <ns1:ErrorDescription>
                        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:updateDocumentStatusResponse/ns0:Acknowledgement/ns0:ErrorDescription" />
                    </ns1:ErrorDescription>
                </ns1:Acknowledgement>
            </ns1:CommunicationResponse>
        </ns1:Output>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($result)/*" mode="step2" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" mode="step2" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="step2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="step2" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/93wkLHW

Comment: No i dont want to use null check condition since condition i want to implement not work with, so I want to check if output empty element then remove it. For example if inside Acknowledgement all the element get null then output get empty acknowledgement so I want remove acknowledgement element empty tag.

Comment: In that case, you can use `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` to be able to further process a result tree fragment created in another template. Edited answer with updated solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: What about if the all three element inside Acknowledgement is empty then Acknowledgement  tag should also not be present but in this case getting output <\Acknowledgement > which is not required

Comment: Well, It's already working as you require. See this: http://xsltransform.net/93wkLHW/1 It will not even populate tree structure if all elements are empty.

Comment: hi Vebbie thanks for your effort but my requirement is different i want to delete specific element  tag for example: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updateDocumentStatusResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001">
<Acknowledgements>
   <Acknowledgement></Acknowledgement>
<ErrorDescriptions>Rakesh</ErrorDescriptions>
</Acknowledgements>
</updateDocumentStatusResponse>
if this tag is<Acknowledgement> is empty then delete only it not other it deleted all the tag which i don't want thats why i asked i want to delete specific tag.my xslt is very large .

Comment: In that case, you need to write specific template to delete nodes you want. E. g. `<xsl:template match="ns1:Acknowledgement[not(normalize-space())] | ns1:ErrorDescription[not(normalize-space())]" mode="step2" />`

Comment: Like this: http://xsltransform.net/93wkLHW/2  This will delete only `ns1:Acknowledgement` and `ns1:ErrorDescription` if they are empty. You can add more nodes separated by pipe ('|') which you want to delete.

Comment: Thanks vebbie it working on online xslt but when i used same code in soa 12c xlst getting error xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exsl not not found

Comment: Have you added `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` at the top where other namespaces are added ?

Comment: yes but getting error during run 
XML-22015: (Error) Function 'http://exslt.org/common:node-set' is not found

Comment: Try adding `xmlns:exsl="<a class="vglnk" href="http://exslt.org/common" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>exslt</span><span>.</span><span>org</span><span>/</span><span>common</span></a>"` instead of that namespace.

Comment: No its not working , i am working on jdeveloper ,might be then you guess

Comment: Which xslt processor/engine do you use ?

Comment: You can check if your environment is working fine using xalan. Add `xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` and replace it's prefix as `<xsl:apply-templates select="xalan:nodeset($result)/*" mode="step2" />`

Comment: XSLT processor/ engine is difficult for me to find but i am using SOA 12c BPEL  where inbuild xslt there .

Comment: xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" and replace it's prefix as <xsl:apply-templates select="xalan:nodeset($result)/*" mode="step2" / I alreday check this but getting same issue

Comment: I am afraid I know a very little about SOA 12c BPEL but I found this for your issue. see if it is helpful to you. https://rathinasaba.wordpress.com/tag/oracle-soa-11g/

Comment: Also, https://www.slideshare.net/DaniloSchmiedel1/whats-stopping-you-from-upgrading-to-oracle-soa-suite-12c point **47**

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but don't know why it is not working

Comment: without using node-set is there any way that i will match Acknowledgement elemnt is present  and then check if null then delete

Answer (score 0):

If you take a top-down aproach with [literal result elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#literal-result-element) you are always going to get that element in the output. Your only choice then is to chain two transformations or use a two pass transformation.

The XPath expression to know whether the [current node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#dt-current-node) is empty (true) or not (false) is:

```
"not(node())"
```

For example, this input document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<updateDocumentStatusResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001">
   <Acknowledgement>
      <Result>SUCCESS</Result>
      <ErrorCode>ErrorCode1375</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorDescription></ErrorDescription>
   </Acknowledgement>
</updateDocumentStatusResponse>
```

With this transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements ="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<updateDocumentStatusResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.be/CommgrService_Message/v001">
   <Acknowledgement>
      <Result>SUCCESS</Result>
      <ErrorCode>ErrorCode1375</ErrorCode>
   </Acknowledgement>
</updateDocumentStatusResponse>
```

### Edit

The previus stylesheet is general. If you want to target specific elements, you need to match those elements with the pattern in the template. Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements ="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ErrorDescription[not(node())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you tried with my xslt still facing same issue. I checked online by using ur information. https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output

Comment: @stans You are creating the element. In that point of the process you could simple not output that element if the information needed is not present. If that's going to be a complex task, you could chain two transformation: your current stylesheet first and mine stylesheet after just for sanitization. Methods for two pass transformation are well described in stackoverflow.